# Print JSON value using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

This should be simple, but its not working for me :(
I am trying to print a value from JSON into an HTML table using jQuery.

```
$('#company1name').html(companies[0].name);
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/S52XP/2/
Any idea what's wrong?
If I alert the JSON element that I need in the table, it works! But I am not able to use it into the table using jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you using `<script>` tags to print the name? Your jQuery works if you use a span instead:

```
<span id="company1name"></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting the html of a script tag does not work the way you expected.  You can use some other element like a `<p>` or `<span>`, in this case I just set the ID on the `<th>` and `<td>` nodes.

Here's the jsfiddle with the loops working.
http://jsfiddle.net/S52XP/3/

If you have the data in json, why not build the table out programmatically instead of using ID attributes all over the place?

Comment: That certainly saves lot of time! :)